# getting the values from array to display in UIPageViewController

Tags: ios

my code as below:-

```
import UIKit
fileprivate func < <T : Comparable>(lhs: T?, rhs: T?) -> Bool {
  switch (lhs, rhs) {
  case let (l?, r?):
    return l < r
  case (nil, _?):
    return true
  default:
    return false
  }
}

fileprivate func > <T : Comparable>(lhs: T?, rhs: T?) -> Bool {
  switch (lhs, rhs) {
  case let (l?, r?):
    return l > r
  default:
    return rhs < lhs
  }
}


class ViewController: UIViewController, UIPageViewControllerDataSource {

    // MARK: - Variables
    fileprivate var pageViewController: UIPageViewController?

    let name = ["dfyguhijo","drtfyguhijopk","srdtfyguio"]

    // Initialize it right away here
    fileprivate let contentImages = ["nature_pic_1",
                                 "nature_pic_2",
                                 "nature_pic_3",
                                 "nature_pic_4"]

    // MARK: - View Lifecycle
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        createPageViewController()
        setupPageControl()
    }

    fileprivate func createPageViewController() {

        let pageController = self.storyboard!.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "PageController") as! UIPageViewController
        pageController.dataSource = self

        if name.count > 0 {
            let firstController = getItemController(0)!
            let startingViewControllers = [firstController]
            pageController.setViewControllers(startingViewControllers, direction: UIPageViewControllerNavigationDirection.forward, animated: false, completion: nil)
        }

        pageViewController = pageController
        addChildViewController(pageViewController!)
        self.view.addSubview(pageViewController!.view)
        pageViewController!.didMove(toParentViewController: self)
    }

    fileprivate func setupPageControl() {
        let appearance = UIPageControl.appearance()
        appearance.pageIndicatorTintColor = UIColor.gray
        appearance.currentPageIndicatorTintColor = UIColor.white
        appearance.backgroundColor = UIColor.darkGray
    }

    // MARK: - UIPageViewControllerDataSource

    func pageViewController(_ pageViewController: UIPageViewController, viewControllerBefore viewController: UIViewController) -> UIViewController? {

        let itemController = viewController as! PageItemController

        if itemController.itemIndex > 0 {
            return getItemController(itemController.itemIndex-1)
        }

        return nil
    }

    func pageViewController(_ pageViewController: UIPageViewController, viewControllerAfter viewController: UIViewController) -> UIViewController? {

        let itemController = viewController as! PageItemController

        if itemController.itemIndex+1 < name.count {
            return getItemController(itemController.itemIndex+1)
        }

        return nil
    }

    fileprivate func getItemController(_ itemIndex: Int) -> PageItemController? {

        if itemIndex < contentImages.count {
            let pageItemController = self.storyboard!.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "ItemController") as! PageItemController
            pageItemController.itemIndex = itemIndex
            pageItemController.imageName = contentImages[itemIndex]
          //  pageItemController.namess = [name[itemIndex]]
            return pageItemController
        }

        return nil
    }

    // MARK: - Page Indicator

    func presentationCount(for pageViewController: UIPageViewController) -> Int {
        return name.count
    }

    func presentationIndex(for pageViewController: UIPageViewController) -> Int {
        return 0
    }

    // MARK: - Additions

    func currentControllerIndex() -> Int {

        let pageItemController = self.currentController()

        if let controller = pageItemController as? PageItemController {
            return controller.itemIndex
        }

        return -1
    }

    func currentController() -> UIViewController? {

        if self.pageViewController?.viewControllers?.count > 0 {
            return self.pageViewController?.viewControllers![0]
        }

        return nil
    }

}
```

and pageitem controller:-

```
    import UIKit

class PageItemController: UIViewController {

    let namess = ["ram","sam","geera`enter code here`"]



    // MARK: - Variables
    var itemIndex: Int = 0
    var imageName: String = "" {

        didSet {

            if let imageView = contentImageView {
                imageView.image = UIImage(named: imageName)
            }

        }
    }
    @IBOutlet weak var name: UILabel!

    var names:String!
    var des:String!

    @IBOutlet weak var desc: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet var contentImageView: UIImageView?


    // MARK: - View Lifecycle
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        contentImageView!.image = UIImage(named: imageName)
        //name.text = namess[0]
       // desc.text = "srdtyugiop fhgkl;"
    }
}
```

This is UIPageViewController. Here i got the output.But i need to display the first name stored in the array should display first then when page control is 2 then ,name should display the index-1.Then at third page it should display the name stored in index-2 .how to do

Comment: **Moderator Note:** Please do not edit your question to make it a completely new question. Ask a new question instead https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask.

Answer (score 0):

```
for i in 0..<names.count {
  let name = names[i]
}
```

Comment: Can you add a little explanation around even simple suggestions such as this, rather than just dumping code?

Comment: there is nothing difficult to be explain. its just swift 4 loop writing syntax. it will count the names and run a loop till on counted condition. will give value from names array by giving index.